# Installing drivers for my wireless adapter

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 and cannot get my wireless adapter to work, also it does not show or appear in the All Settings-> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

I have also tried using the CD to install the drivers but it does not work.

Comment: are you running ubuntu on a live cd or usb?? or a virtual machine?

Comment: Please run the script that is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>